# Swift package issue for Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, facebook-sdk-4.0

I recently updated my xcode, and previously the SDK and swift package was running smoothly but somehow it is showing me the swift package issue and derived data issue, So I tried to delete the derived data and reinstall the swift package but the issue is still remain same.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried implementing it from cocoapods by installing FBSDK?
I struggled a bit to install the facebook sdk following the steps,
you have no more information if what you are trying to do is call the import FBSDKLoginKit or some specific method?

Comment: yes from cococa pods it install properly, but no from swift package

Comment: I took this github repository that Facebook provides and the truth did not have any problem with the use of the application, the truth is that I do not know what it has to do differently with the tutorials that fb gives you with this, but this helped me more I hope this helps you.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/